# what is the difference between ID_SERIAL and ID_SERIAL_SHORT udev attributes for a USB descriptor

Tags: c, usb, linux-device-driver, udev

What are the differences between `ID_SERIAL` and `ID_SERIAL_SHORT` udev properties. How udev is assigning values for these 2 udev property IDs. I am writing USB driver and I am using `udev_device_get_property_value()` method to get values for udev properties. in this case I can see there are 2 similar attributes as mentioned above. I couldn't find an explaining document for these information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ID_SERIAL_SHORT` value comes from the `iSerial` string (if present) in the USB device descriptor. The `ID_SERIAL` value is constructed in software and made up from various strings (vendor or manufacturer, model or product, and serial number if present) separated with `_`.

You can use `udevadm info [DEVPATH|FILE]` command to look at the udev properties (specifying a specific `DEVPATH` or `FILE` as appropriate).

Comment: I will check this and verify. Thanks for the information.